# Nginx VOD Transcoding

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, streaming, mpeg-dash, adaptive-bitrate

I'm trying to setup MPEG-DASH video on demand streaming using nginx. I came across the [nginx vod module](https://github.com/kaltura/nginx-vod-module/) which works great with dash.js but am wondering if anyone has managed to get real-time transcoding working.

I've currently got it setup to play H264 MP4 local files, producing a MPD manifest for a single MP4. I know I can transcode multiple versions of the video and store them on the server, creating a multi URL manifest, but I only have limited space on the server so am not able to do this. Instead, I'm trying to find a way to transcode in real-time to allow more adaptive bitrate streaming like is possible with the [nginx rtmp module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) and ffmpeg (however with MPEG-DASH instead of RTMP since I don't want to use flash).

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Transcoding is generally more slower than actual play back.
Is your server has enough processing power for that?
Also, MP4 output is not playable until the whole file is processed.

If you can solve the performance/timing problem, other realtime broadcast capable format (eg. mpeg2ts) could be incorporated. I'm afraid this could worsen the  situation.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan already mentioned transcoding is usually slower than playback. Also a tradeoff between speed and quality has to be made. If you are looking for fast (talking about 20 times real time) MPEG-DASH transcoding, you can give services, like [bitmovin.com](https://www.bitmovin.com/) a try. This is what did the job for me.